# looking for an opensource in memory database with indexes

Tags: cassandra, hazelcast, ignite, in-memory-database, redis-cluster

we are looking for an opensource in memory database which can support indexes.

The use case is that we have lot of items that are going to grow in a big way.
Each item has a few fields on which we need to query. 
Currently we store the data in application's memory. However with increasing data, we have to think about distributing/sharding the db.

We have looked at a few options

1. ***Redis cluster*** could be used, but it does not have the concept of
   indexes or SQL like queries.
2. ***Apache Ignite*** is both in-memory, and distributed as well as provides
   SQL queries. However, the problem is that ignite fires all
       queries into all master nodes, so that the final result will be
       slower than the slowest of those queries. It seems like a problem
       because a non performing/slow node out of a number of nodes can
       really slow down the application a lot. Further in ignite, reads are
       done from the masters and slaves are not used, so that it is
       difficult to scale the queries. Increasing the nodes will have
       negative impact as the no of queries will increase and it will be
       even slower.
3. ***Cassandra*** - The in-memory option in cassandra can be used, but it
   seems that the max size of a table per node can be 1 GB. If
       our table is more than 1 GB, we will have to resort to partitioning
       which will inturn lead cassandra to make multiple queries(one per
       node) and it is a problem(same as ignite). Not sure whether reads in
       cassandra in-memory table can be scaled by increasing the number of
       slaves.

We are open to other solutions but wondering whether the multi-query will be a problem everywhere(like hazelcast).

The ideal solution for our use case would be an in-memory database with indexes which could be read scaled by increasing the number of slaves. Making it distributed/sharded will lead to multiple queries and we are reluctant because one erring node could slow the whole system down.

Comment: Could you be more specific what you mean by multi-query in your use-case?
Also you say that you don't want to do any sharding. Could you describe your use-case?

Comment: actually the original plan was to do sharding...but in a sharded environment, each query will execute on all the nodes(that is what i meant with multi-query), so that if a node is slow, it will slow the whole application down. If there is no way to avoid one query executing on all the nodes, we were thinking if you should avoid sharding and instead scale reads by replication.. The use case just involves querying a huge table with indexes with ms latency and lots of parallel queries.

Comment: I would also add that Ignite supports distributed joins. If the join keys are colocated and indexed, then such queries execute very fast.

Comment: Can you use key-value API or only SQL? I believe that when using key-value API, every database you have listed will go precisely to the node where the data resides.

Answer (score 11):

Hazelcast supports indexes (sorted & unsorted) and what is important **there is no Multi-Query problem with Hazelcast**.

Hazelcast supports a `PartitionPredicate` that restricts the execution of a query to a node that is a primaryReplica of the key passed to the constructor of the `PartitionPredicate`. So if you know where the data resides you can just query this node. So no need to fix or implement anything to support it, you can use it right away.
It's probably not reasonable to use it all the time. Depends on your use-case.

For complex queries that scan a lot of data but return small results it's better to use `OBJECT` inMemoryFormat. You should get excellent execution times and low latencies.

Answer (score 9):

Disclaimer: I am GridGain employee and Apache Ignite committer.

Several comments on your concerns:

1) Slow nodes will lead to problems in virtually any clustered environment, so I would not consider this as disadvantage. This is reality you should embrace and accept. It is necessary understand why it is slow and fix/upgrade it.

2) Ignite are able to perform reads from slaves both for regular cache operations [1] and for SQL queries executed over REPLICATED caches. In fact, using REPLICATED cache for reference data is one of the most important features allowing Ignite to scale smoothly.

3) As you correctly mentioned, currently query is broadcasted to all data nodes. We are going to improve it. First, we will let users to specify partitions to execute the query against [2]. Second, we are going to improve our optimizer so that it will try to calculate target data nodes in advance to avoid broadcast [3], [4]. Both improvements will be released very soon.

4) Last, but not least - persistent layer will be released in several months [5], meaning that Ignite will become distributed database with both in-memory and persistence capabilities.

[1] https://ignite.apache.org/releases/mobile/org/apache/ignite/configuration/CacheConfiguration.html#isReadFromBackup()

[2] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-4523

[3] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-4509

[4] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-4510

[5] http://apache-ignite-developers.2346864.n4.nabble.com/GridGain-Donates-Persistent-Distributed-Store-To-ASF-Apache-Ignite-tc16788.html

Answer (score 1):

I can give opinions on cassandra. Max size of your table per node is configurable and tunable so it depends on the amount of the memory that you are willing to pay.  Partitioning is built in into cassandra so basically cassandra manages it for you. It's relatively simple to do paritioning. Basically first part of the primary key syntax is partitioning key and it determines on which node in the cluster the data lives.

But I also guess you are aware of this since you are mentioning multiple query per node. I guess there is no nice way around it.

Just one slight remark there is no master slaves in cassandra. Every node is equal. Basically client asks any node in the cluster, this node then becomes coordinator nodes and since it gets partitioning key it knows which node to ask the data for and it gives it then to the client.

Other than that I guess you read upon cassandra enough (from what I can see in your question)

Basically it comes down to the access pattern, if you know how you are going to access your data then it's the way to go. But other databases are also pretty decent.

Indexing with cassandra usually hides some potential performance problems. Usually people avoid it because in cassandra index has to be build for every record there is on whole cluster and it's done per node. This doesn't really scale. Basically you always have to do query first no matter how ypu put it with cassandra.

Plus the in memory seems to be part of the DSE cassandra. Not the open source or community one. You have to take this into account also.